# Browsershots/Puppeteer does not work properly on Laravel-Sail

Tags: laravel, docker, puppeteer, laravel-8, laravel-sail

using [Laravel-Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail), which is basically a convenient way to generate a `docker-compose.yml` to have a Webserver, MariaDB etc. locally, is causing trouble when it comes to the use of [Browsershots](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot), a Laravel-Package that provides [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

### Before I start

First of all: Puppeteer itself is working, as I extended the docker file and rebuilt the image.

### What is the problem?

This part of my pdf-generation method is running forever and fails with timeout.

```
$view      = view('pdf.user', compact('user'));
$body_html = $view->render();

return response()->streamDownload(function () use (
    $body_html
) {
    echo Browsershot::html($body_html)->format('A4')
        ->margins(0, 0, 0, 0)->showBackground()
        ->addChromiumArguments([
            'font-render-hinting' => 'none',
        ])->noSandbox()->waitUntilNetworkIdle()->pdf();
});
```

As it turns out, this line within the blade-template is causing the issue:

```
<img src="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" class="h-24 w-24">
```

Using tinker in the container, I found out that the `assets()` helper returns

```
asset('images/logo.png')
> http://myapp.test/images/logo.png
```

which is fine.

If I use a random image coming from another URL (not-dockerized), e.g. `https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` the view is being loaded and rendered fine.

So my question is: What could possibly be the problem here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't yet have an answer to this, but I think I've got a very similar problem in Laravel Sail when trying to use wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF files.

From the stock sail configuration, it does return a PDF except that; unfortunately, any externally linked images are empty due to being unresolvable using the site's local name (tts.test) from within the sail container.

If I add a reference to tts.test pointing to 127.0.0.1 into the container's /etc/hosts file, then the assets are now technically resolvable, but the process hangs until it times out.

What is very curious is that from a `ps -ef | grep wkhtmltopdf` command, I can see the hanging command including the location of the temporary HTML file it is working on, and if I run the same command interactively from `sail shell` then it produces the PDF output perfectly!!
If I discover why it is hanging, I'll post an update here.